# QML import rcc modules

Tags: qt, module, qml, rcc

I try to create an application in which I use rcc modules but I get the error "modules not installed".

I have the following folders and files:

```
MainFolder
  |_Folder1
    |_Folder11
       |_qmldir
       |_MyButton.qml
  |_Folder2
    |_qmldir
    |_MyComponent.qml
Application
  |_application.pro
  |_main.cpp
  |_main.qml
  |_rccFolders
    |_folder11.rcc
    |_folder2.rcc
```

My qmldirs contain:

In Folder11:

```
module MainFolder.Folder1.Folder11
MyButton 1.0 MyButton.qml
```

In Folder2:

```
module MainFolder.Folder2
MyComponent 1.0 MyComponent.qml
```

The main.cpp:

```
 #include ...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QString sourcePath="C:/path_to_rcc_files/";
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

  QResource::registerResource(sourcePath+"folder11.rcc");
  QResource::registerResource(sourcePath+"folder2.rcc");

  engine.addImportPath(":/"); //to use .rcc files
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

  return app.exec();
}
```

The main.qml:

```
//QML imports
import MainFolder.Folder1.Folder11
import MainFolder.Folder2

ApplicationWindow
{
  ...
}
```

But when I execute the application, I get:

```
qrc:/main.qml:... module "MainFolder.Folder1.Folder11" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:... module "MainFolder.Folder2" is not installed
```

What is wrong in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may [debug resource problems](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html#qml-import-path) (go to Debugging section at the end) using `QML_IMPORT_TRACE`
2. It says `import <ModuleIdentifier> <Version.Number> [as <Qualifier>]` so be sure to try:

```py
 import MainFolder.Folder1.Folder11.MyButton 1.0
 import MainFolder.Folder2.MyComponent 1.0
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't understant with the doc how to use that QML_IMPORT_TRACE. I added it to environment variables with value 1 but how do I get the trace? They say "before running the QML Scene", what does that mean?

Comment: Do you use and IDE, or compile via console? In windows, open cmd, navigate to executable, use `SET QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1` and then run the exe. Output is shown in console

Comment: I use QtCreator.

Comment: There should be a "Application output" tab

Comment: It works, I have the outputs. In fact, you have to close and open QtCreator again to take the environment variable QML_IMPORT_TRACE into account. So I'll search my module error with that.

Comment: If you find the cause, report back :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use an import path with `qrc:` prefix:

```
engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");
```

I am not completely sure (and actually the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#addImportPath) says both the `:/` and `qrc:/` notations should work), but I remember I had some similar issues in the past. At least in my apps (where I use a similar structure) I always use the `qrc:/` prefix.